# keyboard shortcuts don't work with switched keyboard layout (20.04)

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, 20.04

I recently got this problem and have no idea why.

when I change keyboard layout in ubuntu 20.04, the keyboard shortcuts don't work in apps.

there seem to be no problem with desktop itself, like I can still use super+A to show apps even with switched layout.
but none of the shortcuts work in apps with keyboard layout changed.

Distro: Ubuntu 20.04
Desktop: Gnome
Keyboard layouts: English, Persian